# Is it possible to query for all users posts created by your Facebook application?

Tags: java, php, facebook

We are wanting to create a Facebook application that people can add to their page, and then when they post content from it on their wall, we want to have the ability for our application to periodically query for posts created by use of this application to pull and display back on our website.  I've perused the documentation and don't see a way, so figured I'd ask incase I'm just missing it.

Thank you,
JT

Answer (score 0):

Here is some thoughts that maybe will steer you in the right direction (I haven't tried this myself).

You can get wall posts by running FQL on [`stream`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) table. Getting all wall posts by user id (`source_id`) seems straight forward, but getting all wall posts made from an app might require some extra work. Doc says:

> If you want to return all the posts from a user's stream that were published through your application, make sure you include the app_id in your query.

Not sure if query will work if you do a search directly by `app_id` field as it is not indexed (but worth trying). If not, then looks like you need to do a search by `filter_key`. Now docs don't really explain what exactly that field means (surprise), but on their [`stream.get`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.get) page from Old REST API it says:

> You can determine the filters using stream.getFilters or querying the stream_filter FQL table. Filters can be user-defined, Facebook-defined (like News Feed/nf or networks), **or for applications (`app_<APPLICATION ID>`)**.

Looks like `app_<APPLICATION ID>` filter is what we need for `filter_key` field (if that still works). If not then play with [`stream_filter`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter) table and see what kind of filters it contains and if there any sort of app filter available. I suspect your FQL might look something like:

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE filter_key = "application" AND app_id = 123456789
```